# Plot x-ticks in histogram matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I would like to plot the corresponding x for a given name. 
by that I mean, for `foo` it has to plot `[10,20,30]` in the form of a histogram and all foo, bar, baz need to be in the same [graph](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/I8_3d_Histogram.PNG).(I don't require 3d :) )

```
import pylab as P
name = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
x  = [[10,20,30],[40,50,60],[70,80,90]]

P.figure()
P.hist(x, 10,  histtype='bar',
                color=['crimson', 'burlywood', 'chartreuse'],
                label=['Crimson', 'Burlywood', 'Chartreuse'])

P.show()
```

Comment: please explain better what you need. what does it mean to plot [10,20,30] as an histogram ?

Comment: Can you help me plot the graph the in the figure attached?. I tried but I failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope this helps you:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

names = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
x  = [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]
colors = ['crimson', 'burlywood', 'chartreuse']

y = zip(*x)
groups = len(x)
members = len(y)
pos = np.arange(groups)
width = 1. / (1 + members)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()    
for idx, (serie, color) in enumerate(zip(y, colors)):
    ax.bar(pos + idx * width, serie, width, color=color)

ax.set_xticks(pos + width)
ax.set_xticklabels(names)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest `ax.set_xticks(pos + 1.5*width)` to center the labels under the groups

Comment: @spinup right thanks, We can let the OP to optimize the view and understand what is doing what...