# subplots in matplotlib using histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, subplot

```
diff  = [[10,20,30],[40,50,60],[70,80,90]]
comp = ["foo","bar","baz"]
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
for foo in range(0, len(diff)):
        x = [diff[foo]]
        name = comp
        color = ['0.1', '0.2', '0.3']
        label = ['1000000','1200000', '1400000']
        y = zip(*x)
        pos = np.arange(len(x))
        width = 1. / (1 + len(x))

        fig = plt.subplot(3,1,foo)
        for idx, (serie, color,label) in enumerate(zip(y, color,label)):
                ax.bar(pos + idx * width, serie, width, color=color,label=label)
        fig = plt.gcf()
        fig.set_size_inches(28.5,10.5)

        ax.set_xticks(pos + 1.5*width)
        plt.ylabel(name[foo])
        ax.set_xticklabels(comp)
        ax.legend()
        plt.gray()
plt.savefig("file" + '.jpg', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.5,dpi=100)
plt.clf()
```

I want to subplot [`foo bar and baz`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19965006/2015933). But when I try to do that using the above code. The data is not being displayed on the graph. Any idea why?

Comment: I found a very nasty shortcut, which I don't like. Using `Montage` to join the images. :)

Something like this

`montage -geometry 500 image1 image2 [...] output`

Comment: You've called `subplots` twice: once before the loop with no arguments, which creates a figure with just one axis, but then in the loop you call it again with `(3,1, ...)`  You want to move that second call to the top and then plot once in each of the three axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing the first `fig` when you call `subplot` inside the loop, here is a fixed version. See that `ax` returned by `subplots` is a `np.ndarray`, so you have to give an index `ax[foo]` to obtain the AxesSubplot object.

```
diff  = [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]
comp = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1)
for foo in range(0, len(diff)):
        x = [diff[foo]]
        name = comp
        color = ['0.1', '0.2', '0.3']
        label = ['1000000', '1200000', '1400000']
        y = zip(*x)
        pos = np.arange(len(x))
        width = 1. / (1 + len(x))
        for idx, (serie, color,label) in enumerate(zip(y, color,label)):
                ax[foo].bar(pos + idx * width, serie, width, color=color,label=label)
        fig.set_size_inches(28.5, 10.5)
        ax[foo].set_xticks(pos + 1.5*width)
        plt.ylabel(name[foo])
        ax[foo].set_xticklabels(comp)
        ax[foo].legend()
        plt.gray()
fig.savefig("file" + '.jpg', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.5, dpi=100)
plt.clf()
```

Comment: Why do you call `gcf()` and resize the figure every time through the loop?  You should use `fig.savefig(...)` instead of `plt.savefig`

Comment: @tcaswell thank you! I've just copied the code from the OP and fixed the problem but did not pay enough attention...